# Spring Boot: How to make a field as mandatory in POST request while in PUT request it should be optional

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, entity

I am using entity class.

Consider a field "Name" is mandatory in request body for `POST` request and for updating i.e., in `PUT` request that "Name" field should be optional.

We don't need to pass the "Name" field again it is not necessary.

So I want to make "Name" attribute mandatory in `POST` request body and optional in `PUT` request body.

Comment: Use different form objects with different validation rules or use validation groups and validate different ones for POST and PUT requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groups parameter in JSR303 annotations.

@NotEmpty annotation applies when accessed via "Existing" interface:

```
public class Greeting {

  private final long id;
  @NotEmpty(groups = Existing.class)
  private final String content;

  public Greeting(long id, String content) {
      this.id = id;
      this.content = content;
  }

  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public String getContent() {
      return content;
  }

  public interface Existing {
  }
}
```

Note `@Validated(Existing.class)` annotation on PutMapping

```
@PostMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting newGreeting( @RequestBody Greeting gobj) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, gobj.getContent()));
}

@PutMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting updateGreeting(@Validated(Existing.class) @RequestBody Greeting gobj) {
    return new Greeting(gobj.getId(),
            String.format(template, gobj.getContent()));
}
```

For above example Json body `{"id": 1}` will work for POST but for PUT you will get HTTP 400 telling you that "content parameter must not be empty". `{"id": 1, "content":"World"}` will be accepted for both methods.

Comment: Thanks! this really helped.